# Get the second last post in a category

Tags: php, wordpress

This is how I got the last post from a category:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=17&showposts=1');?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>   
<?php the_title();?>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Now what I want is to get the second last post in the category. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `offset` argument to 1.

```
query_posts('cat=17&showposts=1&offset=1');
```

[Parameters Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters).